# Is it possible to instantiate a Java form from within an XSLT stylesheet?

Tags: java, xml, forms, xslt, instantiation

I'm not well-versed in Java nor XML/XSLT but I've inherited a project using both, and my situation boils down to this: I have an XSLT stylesheet that uses Xalan to modify a database based on the data in an XML document. I want to be able to do a comparison against existing database information, and if a probable match is found, instantiate a Java form to ask the user whether or not to overwrite the matching information, or keep it, or modify it or whatever, then modify the database based on the user input.

I've found lots of advice on how to call Java methods, and this project obviously uses them, but I've never seen anything on instantiating forms...can it be done?

Comment: Do you have an ID which represent the database set in the xml?

Comment: What exactly does *form* mean in this context (Swing, HTML, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible in principle to call any Java method from Xalan, including methods that communicate with the user. But I'm not sure this is a good design. I would invert the logic: have a Java application that does the things best done in Java, which calls an XSLT stylesheet to do the things best done in XSLT.